# Play video by Service in Android?

Tags: android, android-service, android-mediaplayer

I want to play VIDEO by Mediaplayer but Mediaplayer is contained in Service in Android. Is it possible? Any idea for me? Thanks!

Comment: a service by definition, has no UI, so playing a video from a service doesn't mean anything and is probably no possible.

Comment: Could I from activity bind to service that contain Media Player to play video?

Comment: @tungdx did u find the solution for your problem?

Comment: @Alliswell No, It seems impossible, I found an other method for my problem.

Comment: Can u please tell me about the new method as am looking for the same

Comment: So I want to switch video that is playing from small to fullscreen without stop video (same Youtube application), I have thought use Service to resolved problem but it can't. I think your problems different my problems, right?

Comment: @tungdx i would like to play video in service class and keep them in background and when needed i can call this class

Comment: I think it can't. I don't know why, but why do you want use this?

Comment: @AndroidOptimist I think it can't but not true. It can. Let's check the project: https://github.com/yixia/VitamioBundle/tree/vitamio-for-mvideo